# How to deactivate "Use colors from system theme" in gnome-terminal via CLI?

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, gnome-terminal, colors

In a script, I'm trying to set the configuration for gnome-terminal. Setting the background color works, but it is overriden by this one option "Use colors from system theme" in the Colors tab in the profile settings. How can I deactivate this with something like gsettings or dconf? I tried, unsuccessfully, to find the right value with dconf-editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're changing the default profile that comes with gnome-terminal, you can use this command to change the preference to use *themes colors*.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/use-theme-colors false
```

Here, `b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9` is the UUID of the default profile of Gnome terminal.

If you want to change settings for another profile, you need to know its UUID. The good thing is most users use the default profile, so it should work most of the time.

---

**Addition from OPs comment**

UUID value for default profile can be fetched using this command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default
```

So, getting it in a variable say `TPROFILE`, stripping off `'` from beginning and end with `TPROFILE=${TPROFILE:1:-1}` and using it as `$TPROFILE` in place of UUID will ensure that default profile is being changed, even if the UUID is changed by the user.

Comment: Awesome, it works. The way I get the UUID is like this: TPROFILE=$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default); TPROFILE=${TPROFILE:1:-1}. Then use $TPROFILE in place of the UUID. This way it'll still work if the UUID of the default profile should change, for whatever reason.

Comment: @LasseMeyer that's great! Edited the answer to add your info. Thanks for the feedbacks